# Find out which app icon is missing in xcode for an app

Tags: ios-appstore, xcode, icon

I already published an app succesfull to the appstore. 
But now something has changed and I get an error when publish again the same app:

- Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad 152x152
- Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad 167x167

How can I find out which of the icons are wrong. I cant see any slot with 152pt in the appicon.xcassets.

I have already created all possible icons with an icon-maker tool and I see all icons of my appicon.xcasset, but now something seems to have changed.
I can't figure out which one is missing.

Any hints ?

Comment: Is this a universal, iPhone, or iPad app?  It's only asking for iPad icons so maybe you made a change to iPad or Universal?

Comment: No did no change. My app is and was always for iphone and ipad. How can I find out which Icon I have to change or add ?

Comment: The error is telling you which icons are missing.  Go to `images.xcassets` and click on `AppIcon`.  You'll see the 76pt 2x (76 * 2 = 152) and 83.5 2x (83.5 * 2 - 167).  If this fixes the problem, let me know and I'll add it to the answer for you to accept.

Comment: Ah. Thats a good hint: 76*2 = 152. I'll try.

Comment: Worked. My tool also produced a file icon152, which was in reality 76pt, but this was another issue. Your hint with  76*2=152 helped me alot. YOu can answer and I will accept. kind regards

Comment: Glad it helped!  Just an FYI, you might get better/faster answers regarding Xcode and app development if you use StackOverflow for your questions.  Most developers use that site, too.

Comment: In order to simplify the entire process of creating icons (and avoid errors like this one), I would suggest you check out [SquareIcon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/squareicon/id1341400785?mt=12). I believe that it makes creating app icons for Xcode projects very simple. Note that this is my own app. You can convert a PNG or JPG (or any common image format) version of your app icon to a .appiconset file which can be put into your app's asset catalog. Check it out [on the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/squareicon/id1341400785?mt=12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you which icons are missing. Go to `images.xcassets` and click on `AppIcon`. You'll see the **76pt 2x (76 * 2 = 152)** and **83.5 2x (83.5 * 2 - 167)**.